# Is it possible to construct a family $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ with the following properties?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

I'm looking to construct a family of subsets $\mathcal{F}$ of the powerset of the naturals $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ with the following properties:

- $|\mathcal{F}| = \mathfrak{c}$
- For all $E_1, ... E_n\in \mathcal{F}$, the intersection $\bigcap_{i=1}^n E_i$ is infinite.

Is such a construction possible?

This is *similar* but not exactly the same as a common real analysis problem of finding an uncountable family of infinite sets in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ such that pairwise intersections are finite.

If there are such families $\mathcal{F}$, how many are there? The properties $\mathcal{F}$ satisfy are again only *similar* to the properties of an ultrafilter, of which there are $2^{2^{|X|}}$ on $\mathcal{P}(X)$, the maximum possible cardinal we would expect (since the collection of all such families $\mathcal{F}$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$).

Comment: What if $\mathcal F$ is all supersets of $2\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: @kimchilover A lovely! Thank you! In that case, unless I'm mistaken, given any countable, cocountable $B\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, we can construct a family $\mathcal{F}_B$ of supersets of $B$ which satisfies the desired properties, yes?

Comment: A minor point.  Unless you're assuming the continuum hypothesis, saying that a set is uncountable isn't necessarily the same as saying it has the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: I'd think so: $B$ countable ensures all the intersections are infinite; $B$ cocountable ensures there are lots of supersets.

Comment: @RobertShore True, my mistake, I'm only expecting the latter condition to be true $(|\mathcal{F}| = \mathfrak{c})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the comments above, for $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ let $\mathcal{F}_A$ be the set of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which contain $A$. Then:

- The intersection of any finitely many elements of $\mathcal{F}_A$ (or indeed all of them) has cardinality $\ge\vert A\vert$.
- The cardinality of $\mathcal{F}_A$ is $2^{\vert\mathbb{N}\setminus A\vert}$.

Putting these facts together we get:

> If $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is infinite and coinfinite - e.g. $A$ is the set of prime numbers - then $\mathcal{F}_A$ has size continuum but any finite intersection of elements of $\mathcal{F}_A$ is infinite.

In particular, Robert Shore is quite right that in general "uncountable" does *not* imply "size at least continuum," but that issue doesn't crop up here since each $\mathcal{F}_A$ is either finite or of size continuum.